# How to read .tracev3 binary log files?

Tags: command-line, macos, logs

In `/var/db/diagnostics` folder there are some compressed binary `.tracev3` log files.

How can I read them what is inside in a formatted way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've found that using `log` command will read these files in a formatted way, e.g.

```
log show file.tracev3 | less
```

Source: [New macOS Sierra Artifacts](https://www.mac4n6.com/blog/2016/11/13/new-macos-sierra-1012-forensic-artifacts-introducing-unified-logging)

See also:

- [Unified Logging and Activity Tracing](http://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/) (+[PDF slideshow](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/721wh2etddp4ghxhpcg/721/721_unified_logging_and_activity_tracing.pdf))

Comment: Any idea if there is a way to do this from the phone itself, or from a windows box?

Comment: @Doug If you've got a command line access on your iOS (jailbreak), possible. On Windows, not, unless you can log in into macOS machine (VM or remote), or there are some external tools for Windows reading these kind of formats.

Comment: I have a jailbroken phone. I don't see the log command on it, but I'm trying to track down a binary. Hopefully I'll get lucky :-).

Comment: I have the same question and I’m on macOS and it doesn’t work. # log show 000000000000458d.tracev3 
==========
/private/var/db/diagnostics/Persist/000000000000458d.tracev3
==========
log: Could not open tracev3 log file: The specified URL did not refer to a valid log archive

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this? I'm running into this issue also.